# Start Python Script on Startup

Tags: python, omxplayer, systemd-startup

I am having trouble getting what seems like a simple task to work. I have created a Python file that I want to begin on startup. I have followed the steps for `rc.local` and `init.d` found [here](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/).

To test this out I have made a practice Python script to play a video. But the ultimate goal is have a [modified version of this program](https://github.com/ephemeralfuture/trron/blob/master/trron_final.py) begin on startup using a PIR sensor. The practice script is just to figure out how to get it working.

Here is my practice script:

```
#! usr/bin/python3

from omxplayer.player import OMXPlayer
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep

VIDEO_PATH = Path("Videos/Scott_eye.mp4")

player = OMXPlayer(VIDEO_PATH, args=['--no-osd', '--no-keys', '-b'])
```

Here is what I added to rc.local just before exit 0:

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/videotest.py &
```

I also followed the steps for `init.d` from the link above.

I tested the practice script out in the command line by typing `python3 /Videos/videotest.py` to confirm it works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: take the video player out of the equation ... log a system message instead ... the graphic subsystem may not be running when your script executes, so the video player will not start

Comment: That link is one of the worst collections of obsolete, incomplete and JUST PLAIN WRONG hints I have seen.

Comment: `systemd` would be the best way to go. You might find the follow article helpful:
https://blog.usedbytes.com/2019/11/run-at-startup-without-rc.local/

Answer (score 6):

As frequently stated here (and other places) `rc.local` has been [*deprecated*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/deprecate) in Linux, and it is not recommended for use. Numerous problems in the use of `rc.local` have been reported here; you should consider another approach.

In general, there are two approaches: `systemd` and `cron`. This answer shows the `cron` approach.

Your question shows the following : `sudo python3 /home/pi/videotest.py &`. Based on this I'll assume that root privileges are, or will be, required to run your script. If you find they are not required, you shouldn't use them - but more on that below:

#### 1. Create/modify the `crontab` file:

We'll use "root's crontab" since you've indicated your script requires root privileges. From the command line:

```bsh
sudo crontab -e
```

This will open root's `crontab` for editing. Before doing so, you may be prompted to designate which editor to use. If prompted to select an editor, choose `nano` unless you're familiar with another one in the list.

If you have determined that root privileges are unnecessary, open your (user `pi`) crontab as follows:

```bsh
crontab -e
```

#### 2. Edit the `crontab` to start your script at boot time

You should now be in your editor with a view of the current version of the `crontab`. Add the following line to the bottom (last line) of the file, then save and exit the editor:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 10; /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/videotest.py >> /home/pi/mycronlog.txt 2>&1
```

Here's what happens:

- at boot time, `cron` tries to execute this job
- `cron` will `sleep` for 10 seconds - this gives the system time to get its resources started
- after 10 seconds, `cron` will call `python3` to run your script located at `/home/pi/videotest.py`
- any output from your script is *re-directed* to the "log" file at `/home/pi/mycronlog.txt`; `2>&1` ensures that `stdout` and `stderr` both go to the designated "log" file.

#### 3. `reboot` and test

Check the contents of your "log" file at `/home/pi/mycronlog.txt` for any error messages the script may have thrown, and adjust fire as necessary. Let us know if you have other questions, or something you don't understand.

Comment: Isn't there @boot?

Comment: so your solution may not work

Comment: And that means it will omly run when you reboot not on startup

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your operanting system (verison would be helpful) inited by sysvinit (/etc/init.d scripts). Newer systems usually use systemd to manage services. rc.local is supported by systemd and may be enabled via following command:

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently running Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). When I ran your suggestion it stated "The unit files have no installation config ... This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl."

Comment: On this site, you can assume it's Raspberry Pi OS (Raspbian) if the OS is not specified. It's been using systemd for several years now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that you need the desktop up and running BEFORE launching a video file. I've had a heck of a time getting an audio program to autolaunch for this reason (Pulseaudio only loads when the desktop does).

Try creating a file /home/pi/.config/autostart/[name].desktop with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=[call_it_something]
Exec= python3 /home/pi/videotest.py
```

If that doesn't work, to see an error log, install a different terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xterm -y
```

Then, in the .desktop file, change the Exec line to:

```
Exec=xterm -hold -e 'python3 /home/pi/videotest.py'
```

(Note the apostrophes that were also added). Then when you reboot, you should get a terminal window showing any i/o and also any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

> **Warning** DO NOT DO THIS

1. sudo nano .bashrc
2. Go to the bottom of the .bashrc file and include the path of the python script and save the changes & exit
3. Reboot the raspberry-pi and your script starts as soon as the Raspberry pi turn's on

Comment: `.bashrc`is NOT for running scripts and DOES NOT run on startup

Comment: It does run on the start-up because it's a service....I run my python scripts following the same protocol, maybe you should re-check yourself & come back again later.

Comment: It is not a service, it's the user config file for the bash shell.  It may run at start-up (for you -- this is not necessarily true although it usually is), but **it runs at a variety of other times as well,** eg. when you open a GUI terminal (see INVOCATION in `man bash`).